# How to install fulltext on sql server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

Trying to install fulltext on my sql server 2008 box.

I went to 'programs and features', selected sql server 2008 and now I get this popup asking to choose either: add/ repair or remove.

I click on add, and it asks me for the location of sql server CD?  I extracted the ISO we have, not sure which file to point it too?

Answer (score 9):

Download the installer from:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=1842

Or for SQL 2008 R2 Express, it is here:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25174

Then go to where you saved it and Unzip the self extracting EXE (right click and click "Extract").

Go to Add or Remove Programs and you can now "Add Features" by browsing to the extracted files.

For full details on how to upgrade and install fulltext search on an existing SQL Server 2008 Express instance see my post [here](http://beweb.pbworks.com/w/page/43820429/SQL%20Server%20Fulltext%20Search)

Answer (score 1):

To add features to a SQL Server installation, you should run the installer itself from the install disc.  As u07ch suggested, you can mount the image, or you can burn the disc.  Once you do that, run through the installer and you'll see the option to add Full Text Search from the "features" page.

Answer (score 0):

Download the microsoft Virtual CD Control Panel and mount the iso as a cd drive on your computer; then point the add/ remove install software at that.

http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/b/6/7b6abd84-7841-4978-96f5-bd58df02efa2/winxpvirtualcdcontrolpanel_21.exe