# How to install FullText Search on SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install fulltext on sql server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869736/how-to-install-fulltext-on-sql-server-2008)

I have recently installed SQL Server 2008 R2

When I tried to create Full Text Search Index

Example

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON DATABASENAME.dbo.MYTABLE
(
column_to_index
Language 0X0
)
KEY INDEX myindex ON DATABASENAMECatalog
WITH CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO
```

It had given me following error:

Msg 7609, Level 17, State 5, Line 4
Full-Text Search is not installed, or a full-text component cannot be loaded.

I tried following

1: Right Click on My Computer and Click "Manage"

2: Double Click "Services and Applications"

3: Double Click "SQL Server Configuration Manager"

But I can't able to perform following 2 steps, as their is No FULL TEXT SEARCH service was their.

4: Double Click "SQL Server Services"

5: Check if "SQL Server Full Text Search" is not started, than Right Click and Press on Start.

Can anyone please guide me how to install full text search on SQL Server 2008

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869736/how-to-install-fulltext-on-sql-server-2008

Comment: Rerun the installer and it is a checkbox option in that, under the database engine option. Not quite a duplicate, because the answers to what @Mitch posted don't actually answer how to install the full text search option.

Comment: Can anyone answer me... Its not duplicate.

Comment: Theres no answer on suggested link...  and its not the one which i asked in this question.

Answer (score 18):

The simplest way to validate whether or not you have installed the Full Text "component" of SQL Server 2008 is to execute the following T-SQL

```
select SERVERPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled')
```

If this query returns a value of '1' then the component is installed.

For further readining on how to get started see: [Getting Started with Full-Text Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142497.aspx)

Comment: I know that full text search is not installed and my question is how to install full text search.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.

Comment: If you don't have it installed: download SQL Server Express with Advanced Services (SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe for example): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/dn434042.aspx and make sure you select `Full-Text Search` feature during the installation process.

Comment: Updated download URL for SQL Server Express with Advanced Services: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299

Answer (score 14):

As the comments suggested, you should probably re-install and make sure you choose the Full-Text Search option (directly under SQL Server Replication).

[image]
<sub>(source: [free.fr](http://vibellet.free.fr/blogsmsdn/SQLServer2008R2NovemberCTPInstallationSt_BABF/image_11.png))</sub>

FYI, this image comes from a [step by step install guide](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vincentbellet/2009/11/10/sql-server-2008-r2-november-ctp-installation-step-by-step/)